# Server error with https://www.customvision.ai/

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I Can't use the following link https://www.customvision.ai/

Comment: Can you please retry, it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please retry the custom vision link the broken link has been restored.
[image]